# Does number of applications on a device impact performance of an android app?

Tags: android, android-intent

While going through Android official documents, I learnt that when an implicit intent is created Android checks which component in other apps can cater to this intent by looking into the manifest file of apps.So does it mean that more the number of apps on device, more time it would take to determine the list of components and hence slower the app performance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes and no.

You can have a very large number of applications running at once, and they are all sharing memory (thus slowing the overall performance of the device).
But, as far as intent resolution goes, only apps that are registered for that broadcast are checked, the number of installed apps that could cause performance problems is very large for it to be considered a problem.

But, if you have a lot of applications with dinamically registered broadcasts running at once, then, your resolution may take much longer (from experience with testing and development, having around 50 dinamically registered apps) can start slowing the device down. This is around milliseconds of difference (but relevant if you do a lot of networking operations).

Finally, the Broadcast system is made in a way that Intent may be "halted, then restarted" if no application can resolve them in the time limit, so the device should never "lock" or cause "ANR - Application Not Responding" if the resolution takes too long.